# Can't update Intel "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software."

Tags: windows-7, drivers, switchable-graphics

I have a problem updating to the latest Intel and AMD driver and have switchable graphics.

I have HP Probook 4730s running Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit and now that have updated to Windows Essentials 2012 I can no longer see images in my Movie Maker 2012 and was able to in the 2011 version.  Microsoft tells me its because I don't have the updated drivers for my graphics card but I have been trying to update and been researching this for over a week now.

I update Intel to the hp sites latest driver and I get the message "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software." and I have tried every which way.  Then I update the AMD but it seems to never be the new updated number.  So read that Intel has to be updated first.  I stepped back to earlier driver download for AMD and tried Intel again and once again get the same message.   I went to Intel site and got the driver download for the Intel 4000 and for a second my movie maker worked but AMD shut down and said was disabled or something was wrong with it.  I tried to update that and it undid the Intel driver and once again my AMD does not seem to have the latest driver and movie maker does not work again.  And of course Microsoft tells me its because my drivers are not up to date for Intel and AMD so I should go to hp site to download.  No kidding been there and tried that a dozen times.   I'm afraid to do anything more until I make sure I am going to do the right steps.

Also not sure do I get the latest driver from Intel site with the 4000 or just get the one from HP which keeps saying I don't have minimum requirements? And by the way I did update Bios according to the HP Support Assistant but it also says nothing about my graphic card drivers being out of date so not sure if I even trust that and maybe should try updating bios again straight from HP for my computer.  I'm not sure how to tell if I have the latest bios compared to what is listed on HP downloads for my computer number.

If anyone has any ideas of the correct way to handle this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Its too long a text, can you trim it down and probably use bullet points to explain, for most people its going to be tl;dr

Comment: Please be specific about the hardware and the driver versions you have installed.  a copy of the dxdiag log would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**
I researched some more on HP site and found this solution so will post it here in case anyone else is having a problem with their switchable graphics and drivers for Intel and AMD Radeon. This is for HP Probook 4730s running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Other version have the switchable graphics enable/disable in Bios but this notebook you can actually now control this in the catalyst application itself.

Go to catalyst and under the power tab change the switcheable graphics mode to manual

Now once in manual mode under power again goto the switcheable graphics which tells you the mode you are currently in and lets you manually toggle between the readeon/disscrete and intel/power saving gpu.

### Your windows index experience will go up after this too.

So for me:

1. I right clicked on desktop selected Graphic Properties.
2. Selected Preferences at top right corner and checked Advanced View.
3. Selected Power option on side tab.
4. Drop down tab "Switchable Graphics Method".
5. Click on Select the graphics processor manually. Click Apply.

   It now works in movie maker 2012.  I have pictures in video.  No More Black Screen and I believe this is good setting for high gaming type issues also.

Hope this helps someone else as well